# Microsoft DNS and Hosts with Multiple IP Adresses

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003

I'm running a Microsoft DNS Server for AD. One of my Servers has two NICs and hence two IP Adresses (192.168.0.10 and 192.168.1.10). The IP Adresses are intentionally in different Subnets, the `1.10` shall only be used for administrative tasks.

The problem is that this configuration registers two IPs for the same Host with the DNS Server. When a client from `192.168.0.xxx` wants to resolve the host name, it may be handed the wrong IP Adress (`192.168.1.10`). There is (intenionally) no route configured between the two subnets.

How can I make the DNS Server hand the correct IP adress to clients? Can I prevent the 1.10 entry from being made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the adapter on the 192.168.1.0 network, TCP/IP Properties, Advanced Settings:

[image]

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much! Will mark as accepted when I checked the DNS Server in 24 hrs.